# Firebase Database Rules for groups

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this Firebase DB which could be changed if necessary:

[image: DB]

The JSON of that DB is:

```
{
  "groups": {
    "1": {
      "name": "G1",

      "points": {
        "1": {
            "name": "p1"
        }
      },
      "visits": {
        "1": {
            "name": "v1"
        }
      },
      "areas": {
        "1": {
            "name": "a1"
        }
      },
      "waypoints": {
        "1": {
            "name": "w1"
        }
      },
      "interests": {
        "1": {
            "name": "i1"
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "G2",

      "points": {
        "2": {
            "name": "p2"
        }
      },
      "visits": {
        "2": {
            "name": "v2"
        }
      },
      "areas": {
        "2": {
            "name": "a2"
        }
      },
      "waypoints": {
        "2": {
            "name": "w2"
        }
      },
      "interests": {
        "2": {
            "name": "i2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "qdRw1khg1ZO1s52YioYCdM4WrD02": {
      "firstName": "AAAA",
      "lastName": "BBB",
      "email": "sdf@sdfs.com"     
    },
    "h3KYDXkPQrY246w6Y6NXIanVoNS2": {
      "firstName": "FF",
      "lastName": "RR",
      "email": "wwf@jjuzhz.com"
    }
  },
  "userGroups": {
    "qdRw1khg1ZO1s52YioYCdM4WrD02": {
      "1": "admin",
      "2": "readwrite"
    },
    "h3KYDXkPQrY246w6Y6NXIanVoNS2": {
      "1": "admin",
      "2": "readonly"     
    }
  }
}
```

I want to define rules to accomplish the following:

- Everyone can create a new group
- Only users of a group can read group data
- Only "admin"s of a group can write data to the group itself, add users and change sub levels of group data but

  - "readwrite" group users can write to the sub levels "points" and "visits"
  - "readonly" group users can not write at all

I have:

```
"groups": {          
  "$groupId": {
    ".read": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).exists()",
    ".write": "! root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).exists() || 
                          (data.parent().val() === 'points' && root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() != 'readonly') ||
                        (data.parent().val() === 'visits' && root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() === 'readonly') ||
                        (data.parent().val() != 'points' && data.parent().val() != 'visits' && root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() === 'admin')"
  }
},
"users": {
  "$userId": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && 
              $userId === auth.uid && 
              newData.val() != null"
  }
},
"userGroups": {
  "$userId": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && 
               data.child(auth.uid).val() === 'admin' && 
               newData.val() != null"          
  }
}
```

But that does not work since

```
data.parent().val()
```

does not return the parent's name string. So I can't do

```
data.parent().val() != 'points'
```

How to solve this? The problem is writing data to groups according to the rules specified.

Comment: What specific requirement is giving problems? And what rule(s) is that requirement encoded into? Do you have an example of the code that fails to read/write? Also, can you replace the screenshot with the actual JSON, so I can potentially test with your data. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Once you grant a user access to data on a certain level, you cannot take that permission away on a lower level. This is one of the reasons why the Firebase documentation recommends flattening data structures. In your scenario, I'd separate the `points` and `visits` into a separate top-level node.

Comment: It is probably best to flatten the data even more like you suggested.

Comment: Yeah, operations on the group level will always be challenging in your current structure. But I'm trying if I can make it secure on the child level anyway. I'll post updates in an answer, since they won't be readable in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Firebaser here. Expect this answer to be updated as I go along.*

My first step is to move the rules for the specific child nodes into that specific child node. That removes the `parent()` problem you've been having. First iteration is:

```
  "groups": {          
    "$groupId": {
      ".read": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).exists()",
      "points": {
        ".write": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() !== 'readonly'"
      }
    }
  },
```

This allows user `h3KYDXkPQrY246w6Y6NXIanVoNS2` to write to `/groups/1/points` (of which the user is an admin), but not to `/groups/2/points` (to which the user only has readonly access).

A next step is to make the rule more generic. To do this I introduce a `$child` variable, which matches any node under the group:

```
  "groups": {          
    "$groupId": {
      ".read": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).exists()",
      "$child": {
        ".write": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() !== 'readonly'
                   || ($child !== 'points' && $child !== 'visits')"
      }
    }
```

This allows user `h3KYDXkPQrY246w6Y6NXIanVoNS2` to write to `/groups/2/name` (which is writeable by any group member), but not to `/groups/2/points` (to which the user only has readonly access).

**Update**: apparently I inverted your logic above, so here's my final take:

```
  "groups": {          
    "$groupId": {
      ".read": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).exists()",
      ".write": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() == 'admin'",
      "$child": {
        ".write": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() === 'readwrite'
                   && ($child !== 'points' || $child !== 'visits')"
      }
    }
```

With this user `h3KYDXkPQrY246w6Y6NXIanVoNS2`:

- **Can** write to `/groups/1/name` because they're admin of group 1
- **Can** write to `/groups/2/points` because they're admin of group 1
- **Can't** write to `/groups/2/name` because they're not an admin of group 2
- **Can** write to `/groups/2/points` because they're a readwrite member of group 2

Comment: @juergen_d: aside from the admin requirement (which Pat's answer captures succinctly), what is still missing from my last snippet?

Comment: Now all users can write to the group except to points and visits. But only admins should be able to do it. I'll have a try to fix that.

Comment: Inside the $child ".write" condition, change it to "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() === 'admin' || (root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val‌​() === 'readwrite' && ($child === 'points'  || $child === 'visits') )"

Comment: Ah, I think I inverted your logic there.

Comment: I ended up using: `root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() !== 'readonly' &&
                    (root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() === 'admin' || 
                     $child === 'points' || $child === 'visits')`

Comment: Check my latest version. It is slightly more succinct than yours, since it captures the admin on the higher level (like Pat did in his answer too). I actually think the final rule is quite readable, so you might be able to stick to the current data model after all. Unless read permission also varies by groups member level, in that case flattening is almost always the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

What if you try nested rules for the "points" and "visits" levels:

```
"groups": {          
  "$groupId": {
    ".read": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).exists()",
    ".write": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() == 'admin'",
    "points": {
      ".write": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() != 'readonly'"
    },
    "visits": {
      ".write": "root.child('userGroups').child(auth.uid).child($groupId).val() != 'readonly'"
    }
  }
},
"users": {
  "$userId": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && 
              $userId === auth.uid && 
              newData.val() != null"
  }
},
"userGroups": {
  "$userId": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null && 
               data.child(auth.uid).val() === 'admin' && 
               newData.val() != null"          
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought so too, but when I run this in the Firebase Rules Simulator then it looks like nested rules are ignored and will not be considered.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the simulator giving you incorrect results? It's working fine for me with multiple tests: http://imgur.com/IEta3zX <- that is testing write to a group from an authenticated user with "readwrite" permission. When I change the write path to /groups/G1/something else it fails: http://imgur.com/e1B76i5

Comment: Also look at the comment of @Frank above.

Comment: Check my last edit, the ".write" inside "$groupId"  should have the "!" removed and instead of `.exists()` at the end try `.val() == 'admin'`

Comment: But then I can not create new groups since I need an admin entry in userGroups which I do not have at creation.