# firebase read/write rules on specific fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

If I have a database with the following fields:

```
name
email
phone
position
pay
```

there are a fair amount of posts showing how you can allow users to allow access their data, or allow admins to access everyone else's data including their own.

The question is, how do you restrict data in firebase security rules to allow say an 'employee' to write only to name, email, and phone, while an admin can write to all the fields including position and pay.

For example, if I'm an employee and I know firebase, what's to stop me from injecting a new amount for 'pay' so that I can change the amount?  Even thought the field may not display, I would have write access to my entire record.  I want to restrict write access to certain fields.  Is this possible?

my guess would be to list out each field, something like:

```
{
"name": ".write...",
"email: ".write...", etc etc
}
```

or use a .validate, but I'm not sure?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming all of these users are under some child called users, and each user's profile has a key that is their `auth.uid`, you could create a rule where users can write to the name category if their position is listed as `admin` or if `$user_id` is their own user id. That way admins can write to anyone's name and users can write to their own name. Similarly, for the `pay` child, only users who have a `position` equal to `admin` can write to `pay`. That could look something like this:

```
{
    "users": {
        "$user_id": {
            "name": {
                ".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/position') == 'admin' || $user_id == auth.uid"
            },
            "pay": {
                ".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/position') == 'admin'"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You would just need to add rules for `email`, `phone`, and `position`.

Comment: ahh ok, this seems to make sense, I'll test it out.  Thanks!  My next question would be, what if you have several fields (30+) that would be write for any type of user?  Do you have to list out all of the fields with the write rules or can they all go into some kind of an array / one object?

Comment: You'd put a `$all` catch-all rule under `$user_id` for that. See my answer to this quite similar question that I gave a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747851/firebase-database-rules-for-groups/44748431#44748431

Comment: This little tidbit, especially the `$` notation to denote a sub-node and then declaring explicit field permissions was SUPER helpful. Saved me from a code update, was able to mark a single field as always writable. Firebase is so slick and always getting better!